# Stuck/leak when allocating data for NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata

I'm stuck at this method and I don't know why!
Can anyone point me to some source code?
Thank you so much!
This is my source code:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
.......
readData = [readFileHandle readDataOfLength:defaultLen]
NSData *decryptedData = nil;
 //check is last buffer of file
NSUInteger exLen = [readData length] % 16;
NSUInteger decryptionLen = [readData length] - exLen;
NSData *dataForDecryption = nil;
   if(exLen != 0)
   {

     stuck at here-> [readData getBytes:dataForDecryption length:decryptionLen];
      //
      decryptedData = [dataForDecryption AES256DecryptWithKey:KEY];
      self.isEndOfFile = YES;
    }
    else
        decryptedData = [readData AES256DecryptWithKey:KEY];
[readFileHandle closeFile];
.......
[pool drain];
```

I've used some functions such as:

```
NSData *dataForDecryption = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:readData length:decryptionLen]autorelease];
NSData *dataForDecryption = [NSData dataWithBytes:readData length:decryptionLen];
```

But I get the same error.
When i'm using 
 `dataForDecryption = [readFileHandle readDataOfLength:decryptionLen];` 
it's stuck at pos above and the size read is 0, although it's not EOF.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 stuck at here-> [readData getBytes:dataForDecryption length:decryptionLen];
```

You're passing `dataForDecryption`, which is a `NSData*`, but the parameter is supposed to be a buffer, i.e. `void*`. If you want a `NSData*`, you should instead use a method like `subdataWithRange:`.

```
dataForEncryption = [readData subdataWithRange:NSRangeMake(0, decryptionLen)];
```